# Fortran Compaq compiler 6.5 can not accept file of data bigger then 1.5MB

Tags: fortran

Fortran users,

I need one practical solution for boring problem. Let's suppose that I have big file of data which I must copy/paste in fortran compiler. But the problem is that fortran can accept file not bigger then 1.5 MB. Is there better solution to don't divide file manual?

Example vector is in the form

V(1)=691627.009959795 - 3428.41117804251*x(1)*x(2) - # 156.91392014999*x(2)**2 + 428391.21915942*x(1)*x(3) - 953.4687530 #88931*x(2)*x(3) + 66317.7918091961*x(3)**2 + 159956.172489745*x(1)

V(2)=691627.009959795 - 3428.41117804251*x(1)*x(2) - # 156.91392014999*x(2)**2 + 428391.21915942*x(1)*x(3) - 953.4687530 #88931*x(2)*x(3) + 66317.7918091961*x(3)**2 + 159956.172489745*x(1) ...

Comment: @Idigas there is no way, suppose that i have this vector of 20MB, how to import in fortran without dividing

Comment: Best would be to write a general program and read that file as data. You may be hiting compiler memory limit.

Comment: @ Vladimir F Can you give some simple example to write the program. Because, I have the data file, but how to read it from fortran because it is big?

Comment: If you read it as data, it is not as big at all. I do not have time to develop a full parser. Also I do not know where you have exactly spaces and #'s. You just need to read the numbers and store them to some array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have CVF installed any more, and looking at the Intel Fortran's manual, limits on the source file size seem to elude me, but generally speaking one should try to avoid putting that amount of data in source code files. Or any amount for that matter.

Of course, this is not always possible *(well, actually it is, but never mind that now ...)*, and while 1.5Mb is not a large amount of data, it is probably more than what is expected in a source file. 20Mb is definitely too much.

Since such file is computer generated (I'm guessing from Mathematica, Octave or some alike system) the easiest way to go about this would be to generate an independent data file, from which data can be read into proper arrays and manipulated afterwards.

*But we would need to know more about how you got the file in question (how was it generated) and what you plan to do with it to offer any further help.

Comment: @Idigas I obtained data in Mathematica and there is no other way to make it different. Vladimir F suggested to read file. I can obtain data in Mathematica or Maple and then I am preparing it to be useful in fortran (I did export from Maple or Mathematica in .for file). What do you think how to generate another code to read data?

Comment: @Pipe - It's gonna be rather hard to read it, in the current format. You better ask Vladimir F. how he thought about going on with it. How does the mathematica code looks like that generates this file? Also, what are the #'s in that file? I'm not familiar their meaning.

Comment: @Idigas 3 can be any sign this to make a boundary, because fortran compiler can not accept long line.

Comment: @Pipe - I'm sorry? 3? Did you mean hash #? Also, fortran compiler can accept long lines (up to 39 if I'm not mistaken, continuation lines) without problems.